# Odd and baffling behaviour of fancybox overlay

Tags: jquery, css, fancybox

I set up a fancybox overlay on my test site. When it opens it jumps straight to the corner first before repositioning itself in the center as per normal. I can't fathom why it's doing this. I've gone through the usual of checking css and fancybox parameters to no avail.

I'm using the latest version 2.1.5  http://www.tpress.co.uk/fancybox.php

Click any of the 3 round blue links at the top right of the page to open the overlay. The overlay itself contains an iframe.

Comment: Could it be the CSS `transition: all 0s ease;` (and all browser equivalents) applied to top and left properties too ?!

Comment: where are you seeing this css rule?